# How to improve questioning a wiki community question?

Tags: discussion

The actual way of creating a wiki community question is:

1. Ask the question.
2. Flag it for moderator review.

Unfortunately, my flag for [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/69100/16833) was rejected, instead the question was closed as not constructive, which means:

> We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

My question is indeed of a kind which does not have one correct answer, or which can be supported by facts or references. But it is also not a question which will likely end in debate, arguments, etc., <strike>although</strike> because it is precisely created for the reason to respond opinions, experiences and maybe some references to e.g. newspaper (like my example regarding Guardian ) or local webpages.

Nonetheless, maybe the close voters don't like the question, because it seems to them to be too specified, and expect that tomorrow someone will ask "Which words from Spanish are used commonly in English", but the close vote as "not constructive" is definitely incorrect.

All the given answers are really great, but in my opinion there could be much more answers containing interesting informations.

Don't get me wrong, I'm not complaining about that the question itself is unpopular to a few users (4 downvotes on just 2 upvotes, currently) and the close voting. I don't care, since I got these great answers. I just tried to create a community wiki question.

So, what can we do to improve the practice?

<sub>And if anyone now says, that this is even not a kind of community wiki question worth, should have a look on this [fantastic question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16059/matryoshka-words)(created as community wiki) and tell me why my question is so much badder than a game.</sub>

Comment: I like to point out, don't read too much into the _reason_ why a question was closed. Voters get presented with a [multiple choice screen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0u9wl.png); very often, the reason for closing doesn't fit nicely into one of those 5 or 6 choices, but that doesn't mean the question isn't a good candidate for closure nonetheless. In this case, I probably would have voted to close, too. You've provided an interesting list of German words, but asking which German words are "common" seems a bit too open-ended for EL&U. (Plus, you got some pretty good answers before it was closed.)

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of CW was revised across the Stack Exchange network last year: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/. Please read that blog post carefully as to why CW is no longer appropriate for questions similar to yours.

With respect to being *not constructive*, your question is a list question, and thus falls under the "polling" category.

As for the other question you refer to, it was created before the CW policy was revised.

Comment: Well, I think my question is somewhere on the brink. I read arguments pro and contra. Nevertheless, let's say my question isn't worth a community wiki: How do I ask this kind of question?

Comment: I’m not convinced it’s a polling question. Certainly the answer I provided is deterministic.

Comment: @tchrist It is a list question, though